# python subprocess sends backslash before a quote

Tags: python, regex, subprocess

I have a string, which is a framed command that should be executed by in command line

cmdToExecute = "TRAPTOOL -a STRING "ABC" -o STRING 'XYZ'"

I am considering the string to have the entire command that should be triggered from command prompt. If you take a closer look at the string cmdToExecute, you can see the option o with value XYZ enclosed in SINGLE QUOTE. There is a reason that this needs to be given in single quote orelse  my tool TRAPTOOL will not be able to process the command.

I am using subprocess.Popen to execute the entire command. Before executing my command in a shell, I am printing the content

```
print "Cmd to be exectued: %r" % cmdToExecute
 myProcess = subprocess.Popen(cmdToExecute, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
(stdOut, stdErr) = myProcess.communicate()
```

The output of the above command is,
Cmd to be executed: TRAPTOOL -a STRING "ABC" -o \'XYZ\'.

You can see that the output shows a BACKWARD SLASH added automatically while printing. Actually, the \ is not there in the string, which I tested using a regex. But, when the script is run on my box, the TRAPTOOL truncates the part of the string XYZ on the receiving server. I manually copy pasted the print output and tried sending it, I saw the same error on the receiving server. However, when I removed the backward slash, it sent the trap without any truncation.

1. Can anyone say why this happens?
2. Is there anyway where we can see what command is actually executed in subprocess.Popen?
3. Is there any other way I can execute my command other that subprocess.Popen that might solve this problem?

Comment: The `"ABC"` should be `\"ABC\"`

Comment: if you are manually constructing the command from scratch then you could create it as a list from the start: `cmd = ['TRAPTOOL', '-a', 'STRING', 'ABC', '-o', 'STRING', 'XYZ']`. Notice: there are no quote inside quotes. There is no shell to interpret them.

Comment: @Pyrce: or triple quotes could be used: `r"""TRAPTOOL -a STRING "ABC" -o STRING 'XYZ'"""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `shlex` to split your command string:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> argv = shlex.split("TRAPTOOL -a STRING \"ABC\" -o STRING 'XYZ'")
>>> myProcess = subprocess.Popen(argv, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
>>> (stdOut, stdErr) = myProcess.communicate()
```

The first parameter to the `Popen` constructor can be an argument list for your shell command or a string, but an argument list might be easier to work with because of all the quotes involved. (See the [Python subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).)

If you want to see the commands being written, you could probably do something like:

```
>>> argv = shlex.split("bash -x -c 'TRAPTOOL -a STRING \"ABC\" -o STRING \'XYZ\''")
```

This makes `bash` echo the commands to the shell by means of the `-x` option.

Answer (score 4):

You asked for the `repr` representation of the string, not the `str` representation. Basically, what would you have to type at the Python interactive interpreter to get the same output? That's what `%r` displays. Change that to `%s` to see the value as it's actually stored:

```
print "Cmd to be exectued: %s" % cmdToExecute
```

Comment: You are right Kirk, %r to %s helped me to understand the real problem.  I misunderstood that python sends the command with \. But, following Alex's comment literally helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: Then you did the right thing by marking him as the answerer! I'm glad we could help. :-)