# How to properly escape mongo dump query when using gcloud compute ssh with subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, subprocess, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I need to execute a `gcloud compute ssh` command and pass in a mongodump command via a python subprocess. The problem is that the query object the mongodump command uses needs to be formatted a very specific way, but the subprocess isn't preserving the exact command (I think):

The mongo query needs to be:

```
--query '{"name": "Ivysaur"}'
```

But the Python subprocess turns it into:

```
--query \'{name: Ivysaur}\'
```

Here's what I have so far:

```py
import json
import subprocess
import shlex

connection_string = "my_mongo_db_connection_string"
database = "my_mongo_database"
collection "my_mongo_collection"
vm_name = "my_gcp_vm_name"
project_id = "my_gcp_project_id"
zone = "my_gcp_zone"

query = {"name": "Ivysaur"}
query = json.dumps(query)
print(query)
# >> {"name": "Ivysaur"} this is the correct format

mongo_dump_command = f"""
    mongodump --uri {connection_string} \
    --db {database} \
    --query '{query}' \
    --collection {collection} \
    --out mongo_dump_{database}_{collection}/
"""

jumpbox_command = f"""
    gcloud compute ssh {vm_name} \
    --project={my_project_id} \
    --zone={zone} \
    --command "{mongo_dump_command}"
"""

subprocess_output = subprocess.run(
   shlex.split(jumpbox_command), capture_output=True, shell=False
)

print(subprocess_output)
```

If I remove the --query line from my mongo_dump_command, it starts working.

Can anyone help me figure out how to pass in the query parameter without it getting garbled up and causing the VM to swallow the request?

Requirements to reproduce:

- A compute engine VM hosted in GCP
- A mongodb database populated with a simple collection of documents
- Python 3.9+
- [gcloud command line CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)
- [mongodb database tools CLI](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools)
- A simple query that you can use to filter a subset of the documents in the collection.

Comment: I find a related case to your concern you can try this [StockOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771957/python-subprocess-sends-backslash-before-a-quote)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was able to solve the problem via some of the ideas proposed in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for sending me the link Jeffery D.

I had to escape all the quote characters I was passing into the python subprocess command:

```py
query = {"name": "Ivysaur"}
query = json.dumps(query).replace('"', '\\"')
print(query)
# >> {\"name\": \"Ivysaur\"}


mongo_dump_command = f"""
    mongodump --uri {connection_string} \
    --db {database} \
    --query \'{query}\' \
    --collection {collection} \
    --out mongo_dump_{database}_{collection}/
"""
```